# create sub array from string in javascript IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have string like

```
var sHTMLTable = "> 24 Hrs.,2,19,20,10,27,16,26,64,246,1|> 12 Hrs.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|> 8 Hrs.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|> 4 Hrs.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|Total,2,19,20,10,27,16,26,64,246,1"
```

I want it to convert to Sub Array

```
var res = sHTMLTable.split("|").map(function (s) {
    var arr = s.split(",");
    return { name: arr.shift(), data: arr.map(Number) };
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Which give me perfect output

```
[{"name":"> 24 Hrs.","data":[2,19,20,10,27,16,26,64,246,1]},{"name":"> 12 Hrs.","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"> 8 Hrs.","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"> 4 Hrs.","data":[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Total","data":[2,19,20,10,27,16,26,64,246,1]}]
```

**But it throws error in IE because of `.map` function i used** . **how can i make it work in IE by achieving same result ?**

Comment: Look for "Array.prototype.map polyfill".

Comment: Dear give detail of the error.

Comment: You do not need map for this. See my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look a wonderful answer of solution all arrays function in IE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc).
In above of your code write

```
 if (!('map' in Array.prototype)) {
Array.prototype.map= function(mapper, that /*opt*/) {
    var other= new Array(this.length);
    for (var i= 0, n= this.length; i<n; i++)
        if (i in this)
            other[i]= mapper.call(that, this[i], i, this);
    return other;
};
}
```

Or simply use `jQuery.map` like this

```
 jQuery.map(a, function( ) { //what ever you want todo .. }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) since you are using jQuery

```
var sHTMLTable = "> 24 Hrs.,2,19,20,10,27,16,26,64,246,1|> 12 Hrs.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|> 8 Hrs.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|> 4 Hrs.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|Total,2,19,20,10,27,16,26,64,246,1"
var res = $.map(sHTMLTable.split("|"), function (s) {
    var arr = s.split(",");
    return { name: arr.shift(), data: $.map(arr, Number) };
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: Dear don't you think `return { name: arr.shift(), data: arr.map(Number) };` again will produce error?

Comment: @AwaisQarni in that case replace it with `$.map(arr, Number)`

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `Array.prototype.map` with `$.map` on the both places:

```
var sHTMLTable = "> 24 Hrs.,2,19,20,10,27,16,26,64,246,1|> 12 Hrs.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|> 8 Hrs.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|> 4 Hrs.,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0|Total,2,19,20,10,27,16,26,64,246,1"
var res = $.map(sHTMLTable.split("|"), function (s) {
    var arr = s.split(",");
    return { name: arr.shift(), data: $.map(arr, (Number)) };
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: This is only if Sagar is using jQuery... (or any library mapped to `$`)

Comment: Yes, jQuery is set as tag of the question :)

Answer (score 1):

**IE** doesn't support map(). Check MDN (Mozilla Developer Network):

map - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Browser_compatibility)

Looks like IE added support for map() in version 9.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version

```
 sHTMLTable = sHTMLTable.split('|');
 for(var i = 0, l = sHTMLTable.length; i < l ; i++){
    temp = sHTMLTable[i].replace(',','_').split('_');
    sHTMLTable[i] = {
       name : temp[0],
       data : temp[1]
    }
 }
```

Check it here in http://jsfiddle.net/GvyuV/