# jQuery validation engine - [IE8] "object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-validation-engine

this error message apears if I'm using the [validationEngine](http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/) in the Internet Explorer 8 (not tried other versions). in this message is written that the problem is at line 714, 4th character, where is this code:

```
if(!required && !(field.val()) && field.val().length < 1 && rules.indexOf("equals") < 0) options.isError = false;
```

I don't know where is the problem

Comment: Neither do we, because there is not enough information and what appears to be at the 4th character here ("`required`") is not a property access. You will have to do some basic debugging yourself and ask a question with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.indexOf` isn't supported in <= IE8.

As a workaround you could create a custom `indexOf()` implementation, placed in perhaps a centralised JS script file targeted for IE8.  For example,

```
// create self-invoking anonymous indexOf() function
(function () {
    if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
        Array.prototype.indexOf = function (obj, start) {
            for (var i = (start || 0), j = this.length; i < j; i++) {
                if (this[i] === obj) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
            return -1;
        };
    }
})();
```

Comment: thats it. I found this function with some others [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc). many thanks