# UI suite for angular which will work with IE8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I couldn't help not to notice that the angular ui project had recently dropped support for IE8.

Unfortunately a decent percentage of my users still use this deprecated browser, and I cannot afford my self to do the same at this point of time.

Has anyone came across a complete UI solution, that resembles angular-ui but still has support for IE8?.

Can I still use Angular-ui with some constraints on IE8 perhaps?.

At the worse case scenario I'll have to use Zurb foundation3 and stab foundation-jQurish code into my angular controllers(F4 is mobile first, thus doesn't display well on IE8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a JavaScript file to supply the functionality missing in IE8 and below.  See this StackOverflow answer for an example.

[Fixing JavaScript Array functions in Internet Explorer (indexOf, forEach, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc)

I just added a JavaScript file with that code and that worked perfectly for IE8.  I even added some conditional browser tags to the reference to the JS file.