# Highlight.js and IE8 error

Tags: javascript

I have come across an error in IE8 using this js:

http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/8.1/highlight.min.js

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'
File: highlight.min.js, Line: 1, Column: 5879

Is there a way to fix this, so that the page works in IE8?
Many thanks

Comment: Well if it is using forEach, that means the developer is not supporting IE8. You can use the pollyfill https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach, but who know what else is going to be broken.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc

Answer (score 0):

As per [`Array.prototype.forEach` MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility), it is available from only IE 9. So you may have to use the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Polyfill) given in the same page.