# Alternative to array.some() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Is there an alternative to using array.some()? 
I've had it in my code for a while but I just learned that its not supported by IE8.

My original code:

```
var list = ['Johny', 'Adam', 'Johny'];
var option = 'Johny';

var foundInList = list.some(function (el) {
    return el === option;
});
```

I could replace it with something like :

```
var test = false;
for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
    if (list[i] === option){
        test = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

But there may be a better way to do the same.

Please help. 
Thanks in Advance

PS: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggq7bwp1/7/)

Comment: you can refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc and see the polyfill section here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your own some method

```
if (!Array.prototype.some)
{
    Array.prototype.some = function (func)
    {
        for (var i in this)
        {
           if (func(i)) return true;
        }
        return false;
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your best solution here is just a bespoke for loop over the entries. Most array mutation methods are not supported in IE8. I would recommend not polyfilling to replace the function because your polyfill may not efficiently replace the function in modern browsers.