# Adding a function to Array.prototype in IE results in it being pushed in to every array as an element

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

I have added the following polyfill to `Array` in the beginning of my project:

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Array.prototype.find = function(predicate) {
    if (this === null) {
      throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
    }
    if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
    }
    var list = Object(this);
    var length = list.length >>> 0;
    var thisArg = arguments[1];
    var value;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      value = list[i];
      if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
        return value;
      }
    }
    return undefined;
  };
}
```

This works perfectly fine in Chrome and Firefox, but on Internet Explorer 11, this function is actually being **pushed** in every `Array` as an element of it, and I can even access it like:

```
var a = [];
a[0]();
```

This is throwing all sorts of exceptions in IE with functions like `.forEach` where I am expecting some data and this function is found.

Here's a screenshot from IE's developer tools, in this case, this array should have just 2 elements, instead of 3.

[image: IE - wrong]

And this is how it should be, from Chrome. In fact, I believe even the actual content is wrong, but i didn't get there yet (it should be an array containing arrays of length 2).

[image: Chrome - correct]

How can JavaScript still behave so wrong in IE11, and how can I correctly add this function to the `prototype` instead of in every `Array` instance?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's not being "pushed" into every array; you added a property to the prototype object, so it's *visible* and *enumerable* in every array instance. That's how prototype properties are supposed to work.

It works in Chrome and Firefox because `.find()` on the prototype in those environments is defined in such a way as to be *visible* but **not** *enumerable*. You can do that in IE by using `Object.defineProperty()`:

```
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "find", {
    value: function(predicate) {
      if (this === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Array.prototype.find called on null or undefined');
      }
      if (typeof predicate !== 'function') {
        throw new TypeError('predicate must be a function');
      }
      var list = Object(this);
      var length = list.length >>> 0;
      var thisArg = arguments[1];
      var value;

      for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        value = list[i];
        if (predicate.call(thisArg, value, i, list)) {
          return value;
        }
      }
      return undefined;
    }
  });
}
```

In addition to property "value", which is clearly the value of the new property, the properties "enumerable" and "configurable" default to `false`. That means that "find" won't show up in any situation that involves iterating through object properties.

Comment: That's a great answer and it works! One final question, I took this polyfill from Mozilla Developer's Network (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) and all of their polyfills use the same approach of directly adding the function to the object's prototype (another example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Polyfill). Should I avoid it altogether and always use `defineProperty`? Or this will be just a problem in `Array`?

Comment: Personally I would use `defineProperty()`, though if you're trying to get things to work on IE8 or older you'll encounter difficulties. You could always fall back to simply adding the property to the prototype if `defineProperty` doesn't work.

Comment: @WillP. yes, prior to IE9 the native prototypes in IE could not be modified.

Comment: Just re-read your earlier comment and realized I was being redundant :P

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) says `enumerable` is false by default. Thus, I consider this a bug in IE11.