# referring the array with a dynamic string name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array.

```
 var ABCD=[{Key:"Milk",Value:"1" },{Key:"Bread",Value:"2" }];
```

now need to find using  the key in this array (ABCD) using a dynamic string value (returned from a `function myFunction("guest_user")`). I am using something like this which is working in all the browsers apart from IE because of the `eval()` and would be great if someone can advise on this.

```
var entry  = eval(myFunction("guest_user")).find(function(e) { return e.Key === "Milk"; });
```

the return value `myFunction("guest_user")` is ABCD which is the array name defined above.

myFunction is returning a request parameter .. .

```
function myFunction(key) { 
  var result = new RegExp(key + "=([^&]*)", "i").exec(window.location.search); 
  return result && unescape(result[1]) || ""; 
}
```

Comment: `myFunction("guest_user").find(...)` and you don't need `eval`

Comment: Why are you using `eval`?

Comment: thats coming as undefined..

Comment: The code for `myFunction()` really needs to be part of this question.

Comment: myFunction is returning me a request parameter

Comment: You cannot access the variable `ABCD` from the string `"ABCD"` without using `eval()`.  Can you put the array inside an object?  `var obj = {ABCD: [{Key ...}];`

Comment: yes, I did , and how do I find?

Comment: var obj = {ABCD: [{Key:"Milk",Value:"1" },{Key:"Bread",Value:"2" }];, how will I find in the array ?var entry  = eval(myFunction("guest_user")).find(function(e) { return e.Key === "Milk"; });

Comment: You could then do `obj[myFunction("guest_user")].find...`

Comment: You really don't say what is it you expect from us. Exactly what result do you expect from a correct solution?

Comment: I need to find the value of an array, the array name is same as the request parameter. I have few arrays, based on the request param the array needs to be find.

Comment: @RickHitchcock  : it works on Chrome not on IE11. 

entry  = obj[(getUrlVar("guest_user")].find(function(e) { return e.Key === "Milk"; I am using as entry.Value

Comment: Should work fine on IE, but `eval` should also work.  Must be a different issue.

Comment: @RickHitchcock thats the strange part 
This is the line which is causing the error ... 

 var entry  = obj[myFunction("guest_user")].find(function(e) { return e.Key === "Milk"; 

I m displaying the value as entry.Value ...

Comment: I now see the problem, and I've posted a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in IE11 is *not* the `eval()` function.  It's the `find()` method.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find, and you'll see that `find()` is not supported in Internet Explorer.

You can, however, add the functionality to IE by using the **Polyfill** from the same link.

That said, it's best to avoid using `eval()` altogether.  You can do so by placing your arrays in an object, such as:

```
var obj = {ABCD: [{Key ...}];
```

You can then reference the appropriate array by calling:

```
obj[myFunction("guest_user")].find(...
```

Comment: var entry  = obj[myFunction("guest_user")].find(function(e) { return e.Key === "Milk" }); 

however we still have find , and its still does nt work on IE... any pointers?

Comment: Thank  you very much!

Answer (score 0):

adding polyfill method ([Adding a function to Array.prototype in IE results in it being pushed in to every array as an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135127/adding-a-function-to-array-prototype-in-ie-results-in-it-being-pushed-in-to-ever) ) and as Rick advised obj[myFunction("guest_user")].find( is working on IE.