# Convert string array to integer array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of strings like `['2', '10', '11']` and was wondering what's the most efficient way of converting it to an integer array. Should I just loop through all the elements and convert it to an integer or is there a function that does this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** and **[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)**

```js
var res = ['2', '10', '11'].map(function(v) {
  return parseInt(v, 10);
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '<pre>')
```

More simplified ES6 arrow function

```js
var res = ['2', '10', '11'].map(v => parseInt(v, 10));

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '<pre>')
```

Or using **[`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)**

```js
var res = ['2', '10', '11'].map(Number);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '<pre>')
```

---

Or adding `+` symbol will be much simpler idea which parse the string

```js
var res = ['2', '10', '11'].map(v => +v );

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, null, 3) + '<pre>')
```

---

**FYI** : As @Reddy comment - **[`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)** will not work in older browsers either you need to implement it ( [Fixing JavaScript Array functions in Internet Explorer (indexOf, forEach, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790001/fixing-javascript-array-functions-in-internet-explorer-indexof-foreach-etc) ) or simply use for loop and update the array.

Also there is some other method which is present in it's documentation please look at **[Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill)** , thanks to @RayonDabre for pointing out.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The only bad thing about this is it takes another array's worth of memory, but luckily my array isn't very big at all.

Comment: For compatibility issues, please note that Array.map() method is not available in IE8 and below

Comment: [_Polyfill_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill) is there..

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the **Number** object.

```
ḷet res = ['2', '10', '11'].map(Number);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
var yourArray= yourArray.map(Number);
```

Using jQuery, you can use the map method as below

```
$.map(yourArray, function(value,index) { 
     return parseInt(value); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to parse int from string is adding a **+** sign before:

```
var res = ['1', '2', '3'].map(function(v){return +v})
```