# JavaScript triple greater than

Tags: javascript

I saw this syntax on another [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608575/jquery-split-and-indexof-results-in-object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-me) and was curious as to what it does:

`var len = this.length >>> 0;`

What does `>>>` imply?

Comment: That's a right shift operator, but why would you right shift by zero?  Is that some kind of cheap way of doing `parseInt`?

Comment: `>>>` always sets the sign bit to zero, even if you shift by zero bits.

Comment: Check this answer about *why* they use in this case the `>>>` operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/what-good-does-zero-fill-bit-shifting-by-0-do-a-0/3082073#3082073

Comment: JavaScript triple angle bracket

Comment: I saw that syntax in https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find ```var length = list.length >>> 0;``` *(same use case as your one)*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the JavaScript >>> operator and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

That's an [unsigned right shift operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342xfs5s%28v=vs.94%29.aspx). Interestingly, it is the only [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift) that is **unsigned** in JavaScript.

> The >>> operator shifts the bits of expression1 right by the number of
>   bits specified in expression2. Zeroes are filled in from the left.
>   Digits shifted off the right are discarded.

Answer (score 118):

Ignoring its intended meaning, this is most likely where you'll see it used:

---

`>>> 0` is unique in that it is the only operator that will convert any type to a positive integer:

```
"string"         >>> 0 == 0
(function() { }) >>> 0 == 0
[1, 2, 3]        >>> 0 == 0
Math.PI          >>> 0 == 3
```

In your example, `var len = this.length >>> 0`, this is a way of getting an integer length to use to iterate over `this`, whatever type `this.length` may be.

---

Similarly, `~~x` can be used to convert any variable into a signed integer.

Comment: can you explain how to iterate using `>>>`?

Comment: @K48 I don't think he meant *iterate*, I think he meant to say this forces length to become a number.  (Otherwise, I am equally confused.)  But here's a great answer that elucidates more:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it

Answer (score 10):

That operator is a logical right shift. Here the number is shifted 0 bits. A shift of zero bits mathemetically should have no effect.

But here it is used to convert the value to an unsigned 32 bit integer.

Answer (score 3):

`>>>` is a bit-wise operator, [zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.3E.3E.3E_%28Zero-fill_right_shift%29).

I think the only effect of `>>> 0` on a positive number is to round down to the nearest integer, same as `Math.floor()`. I don't see why this would be necessary in your example, as generally a `.length` property (e.g. of an `Array`) would be an integer already.

I've also seen the slightly shorter `~~` used in the same way: `~~9.5 == 9; // true`.

Comment: I doubt it is the same as `Math.abs()` when used for negative numbers.

Comment: If you do `>>> 0` on a negative number it converts it to 2's compliment, then does the right shift.  Therefore `-14 >>> 0 == 1073741820`. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342xfs5s%28v=vs.94%29.aspx)

Comment: @AlKepp - yup, I saw the error and fixed it - should have tested first, but this was clearly a quick-draw question :).