# What's array.length >>> 0; used for?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   1. [What good does zero-fill bit-shifting by 0 do? (a >>> 0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3081987/what-good-does-zero-fill-bit-shifting-by-0-do-a-0)
>   2. [JavaScript triple greater than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718711/javascript-triple-greater-than)

I was digging through some MooTools code, and noticed this snippet being used in every array method:

```
var length = this.length >>> 0;
```

What's the benefit of doing this? It doesn't seem to me like it's some max length thing, as `3247823748372 >>> 0 === 828472596` and `3247823748373 >>> 0 === 828472597` (so, both are 1 higher, if it were for maxLength wouldn't it be better to do something like `var length = Math.min(this.length, MAX_LENGTH)`?).

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718711/javascript-triple-greater-than

Comment: Ah, I was wondering why I couldn't find anything but obviously search engines don't 'recognize' >s... Thanks for the link, that explains a lot ^^,

Comment: @Reanimation: But were you asking for the reason/benefit of this approach compared to others? That duplicate doesn't seem to answer that part of your question.

Comment: I closed the question as it asks the same thing as the duplicate as it stands. But if you are wondering why it's being used on an integer (in which case `>>> 0` doesn't seem to make a lot of sense), feel free to edit the question and I'll reopen it.

Comment: @RightSaidFred: Actually it does, the second answer demonstrates how it converts to positive 32bit int which seems a logical thing to do on array lengths to be foolproof, some moron might set it to be '10k' ;)

Comment: ... and the other duplicate link takes care of that part.

Comment: Ah, you mean the link that was added *after* you closed the question. Yes, that's a much better duplicate. Thankfully a member of the community found and added it.

Comment: I don't think that either duplicate question address why MooTools would use this operator on existing Array `length` properties. It is ensuring that the value returned by `length` is a positive 32-bit integer, and yet (as noted in the first duplicate) the specification already declares that the length property must be such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`>>>` is the bitwise ["zero-fill right shift" operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.3E.3E.3E_%28Zero-fill_right_shift%29).

JavaScript numbers can represent both integers and floating point numbers. Sometimes you only want an integer. Any positive JavaScript Number representing a number less than 2^32 will be rounded down (truncated, as in `Math.floor`) to the nearest integer. Numbers ≥ 2^32 are turned to 0. Numbers less than 0 will turn into a positive value (thanks to the magic of two's-complement representation).

However, `this.length` would presumably ALWAYS be an integer less than 2^32…so I can't explain why the code would be doing that. The result should be the same as `this.length`.

Comment: That says nothing about "used for"

Comment: However, shifting 0 bits doesn't really do much.

Comment: it does. for instance, any floating point numbers are 'cut'. Furthermore it implicitly cast the value into an int32 value. Even "illegal" strings would be casted to `0`.

Comment: @jAndy, `>>> 0` converts to `UInt32`, while `Int32` is a signed integer (which you can convert to using `| 0`). `0xFFFFFFFF | 0` = `-1` while `0xFFFFFFFF >>> 0` = `4294967295`

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be the safest way to ensure length is a *non-negative* (32-bit) *integer*.

Just another example of where JavaScript lacks proper standard functions, this time for save conversion of unknown types into, well, 32-bit unsigned integers.