# javascript: triple > - what does it mean

Tags: javascript

I was searching an indexOf polyfill for IE8, and I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629183/why-doesnt-indexof-work-on-an-array-ie8).
The accepted answer suggests this code:

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
Array.prototype.indexOf = function(elt /*, from*/)
{
var len = this.length >>> 0;

var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
from = (from < 0)
     ? Math.ceil(from)
     : Math.floor(from);
if (from < 0)
  from += len;

for (; from < len; from++)
{
  if (from in this &&
      this[from] === elt)
    return from;
}
return -1;
```

};
}

I never see before a triple >:

```
var len = this.length >>> 0;
```

What is?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718711/javascript-triple-greater-than

Answer (score 1):

This is [Zero-fill right shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) bitwise operator.