# What is the use of length property of an Object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

This code is polyfill of Array.prototype.map given on Mozilla Developer Network. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.19
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19
if (!Array.prototype.map) {

  Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {

    var T, A, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(' this is null or not defined');
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| 
    //    value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
    //    method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array(len) 
    //    where Array is the standard built-in constructor with that name and 
    //    len is the value of len.
    A = new Array(len);

    // 7. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 8. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue, mappedValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal 
      //    method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
        //    method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Let mappedValue be the result of calling the Call internal 
        //     method of callback with T as the this value and argument 
        //     list containing kValue, k, and O.
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);

        // iii. Call the DefineOwnProperty internal method of A with arguments
        // Pk, Property Descriptor
        // { Value: mappedValue,
        //   Writable: true,
        //   Enumerable: true,
        //   Configurable: true },
        // and false.

        // In browsers that support Object.defineProperty, use the following:
        // Object.defineProperty(A, k, {
        //   value: mappedValue,
        //   writable: true,
        //   enumerable: true,
        //   configurable: true
        // });

        // For best browser support, use the following:
        A[k] = mappedValue;
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }

    // 9. return A
    return A;
  };
}
```

What I do not understand is these two lines -

var O = Object(this);

var len = O.length >>> 0;

Can someone please explain this to me? What is the use of calling length property on an Object(which has become an array after passing 'this' to it, I suppose) and then zero-fill right shifting it by 0?

Comment: It is the total no of elements present in that object

Comment: This is a duplicate of numerous questions, please use the search.

Comment: Can you please comment here the link of other question like this?

Comment: The code is commented. Have you read the comments? What is it you don't understand about the comments?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript triple greater than](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718711/javascript-triple-greater-than)

Comment: Why is it that an array is being converted to Object and its length property is being called upon?

Comment: Obviously, it needs the length in order to iterate over the elements of the array. You don't really need to worry about the `Object(this)`. If `this` is an array, it does nothing. This type of coding is to deal with certain kinds of objects which are not arrays. For instance, I can invoke `map` as `Array.prototype.map.call(5, function() { })` and it will work. In this case, the line you are wondering about turns `5` into an object, whose `length` property I can examine (although in that case it doesn't exist; the `>>> 0` idiom will transform the `undefined` into `0`.

Comment: @torazaburo You could've added this text into the answer box and I would've accepted it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, it needs the length in order to iterate over the elements of the array.

You don't really need to worry about the `Object(this)`. If this is an array, it does nothing. This type of coding is to deal with certain kinds of objects which are not arrays. For instance, I can invoke `map` as `Array.prototype.map.call(5, function() { })` and it will work (returning `[]`). In this case, the line you are wondering about turns `5` into an object, whose `length` property I can examine (although in that case it doesn't exist; the `>>> 0` idiom will transform the `undefined` into `0`).