# Swift SHA1 function without HMAC

Tags: javascript, swift, sha1, commoncrypto

i try to get SHA1 working in swift.
without using CommonCrypto since it is not default in swift.

please see https://gist.github.com/wdg/f7c8c4088030c59f0f45 (since it's a little to big to post)

if i run a test case in Xcode:

```
func test_sha1() {
    XCTAssertEqual(sha1("test"), "a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3")
}
```

it will fail, and return `2d891cc96e32c32e8d26704d101208b954f435a5`

i got the hash with:

```
$ php -r "echo sha1('test');echo(PHP_EOL);"
a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3
```

i think the problem is that in the javascript file they use `>>>` and i don't know what this operator is.
So i have used `>>`.

i hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718711/javascript-triple-greater-than

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a solution, there was something wrong with the rotate function.

i have changed the rotate function to

```
func rotate(n: Int, _ s: Int) -> Int {
    return ((n << s) & 0xFFFFFFFF) | (n >> (32 - s))
}
```

and now it works.

Answer (score 1):

Use Common Crypto for several reasons: 1. It is correct. 2. It is FIPS 140-2 certified. 3. It is over 1000 times faster than a code based Swift implementation.

Note: Common Crypto uses the hardware encryption engine.

Just add a bridging header with the include:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```

Example code for SHA256 (SHA1 should no longer be used):

```
func sha256(dataIn dataIn:NSData) -> NSData {
    let digest: NSMutableData! = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH));
    CC_SHA256(dataIn.bytes, CC_LONG(dataIn.length), UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(digest.mutableBytes));
    return digest;
}
```

or

```
func sha1(dataIn dataIn:NSData) -> NSData {
    let digest: NSMutableData! = NSMutableData(length: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH));
    CC_SHA1(dataIn.bytes, CC_LONG(dataIn.length), UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(digest.mutableBytes));
    return digest;
}
```

or

```
func sha1(string string: String) -> [UInt8] {
    var digest = [UInt8](count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH), repeatedValue: 0)
    if let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        CC_SHA1(data.bytes, CC_LONG(data.length), &digest)
    }
    return digest
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i need to use SHA1 in a framework, and since frameworks don't support a bridging header it is not useable.

Comment: [bugreport.apple.com](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login.html?appIdKey=77e2a60d4bdfa6b7311c854a56505800be3c24e3a27a670098ff61b69fc5214b&sslEnabled=true&rv=3). There are solutions house Common Crypto in a Framework, each SO. There is also a Swift implementation of SHA1 on GitHub. It also helps to be more specific in the question.