# What does >>>= mean?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

While I was checking the lodash code, I came up with a question I was curious about.

```js
// slice.js
function slice(array, start, end) {
  let length = array == null ? 0 : array.length
  if (!length) {
    return []
  }
  start = start == null ? 0 : start
  end = end === undefined ? length : end

  if (start < 0) {
    start = -start > length ? 0 : (length + start)
  }
  end = end > length ? length : end
  if (end < 0) {
    end += length
  }
  length = start > end ? 0 : ((end - start) >>> 0)
  start >>>= 0

  let index = -1
  const result = new Array(length)
  while (++index < length) {
    result[index] = array[index + start]
  }
  return result
}

export default slice
```

1. Specifically, I am curious about why this code exists in this part.

```js
((end - start) >>> 0)
```

> As far as I know, the bit operator shifts the position of a binary number, but I am curious why it shifts 0 times.

2. `>>>=`

- And `>>>=` This operator is the first time I saw it.
  Does anyone know what it means?

Comment: Possibly answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718711/javascript-triple-greater-than/7718947

Comment: It converts the number to uint32

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript triple greater than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718711/javascript-triple-greater-than) or [What does this symbol mean in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549780/what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-javascript)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822350/what-is-the-javascript-operator-and-how-do-you-use-it

Answer (score 5):

`>>>` is called unsigned right shift (or zero fill right shift). You may have known of left/right shift.
Basically it shifts the specified number of bits to the right. You can find it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unsigned_right_shift)

So `>>>=` is basically **the right shift assignment**.

```
a >>>= b
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = a >>> b
```

Answer (score 1):

The unsigned right shift operator (`a >>> b`) does shift the bits of the variable `a` by `b` bits as you said.

It always returns a positive integer, so `a >>> 0` would be used to make sure that the input isn't say, negative, or a string, or otherwise not a positive integer.

`a >>>= b` is similar to `a += b`, that is, it applies the right shift `b` to `a` and then assigns the output to `a`, similar to how `a += b` adds `b` to `a` and then assigns the result to `a`. So `a >>>= b` is equivalent to `a = a >>> b` like `a += b` is equivalent to `a = a + b`.