# How to convert decimal numbers to binary in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I do not understande code below which is used to convert decimal number to a binary.

```js
function dec2bin(dec){
  return (dec >>> 0).toString(2);
}

console.log(dec2bin(-5));
```

Comment: A relevant related question: [JavaScript triple greater than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718711/javascript-triple-greater-than)

Answer (score 0):

`dec >>> 0` is an [unsigned 32-bit right-shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unsigned_right_shift) of zero.

This has the effect of

a) truncating the non-integer part of the number

b) converting the number to 32-bit

c) removing the sign bit from the 32-bit number

`someNumber.toString(2)`

will convert to a string representation of the binary value of `someNumber`.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification, I have understood the process, but I still do not know  how (( >>> Zero fill right shift )) works with zero, like what is the result of 
( -7 >>> 0 ) and (7 >>> 0 ) ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function dismailToBinary(num) {
  let binary = "";
  while (num > 0) {
    let digit = num % 2;
    binary = "" + digit + binary;
    num = parseInt(num / 2);
  }
  return binary;
}
console.log(dismailToBinary(5));
```

```js
function decimalToBinary(num) {
  let binary = "";
  while (num > 0) {
    let digit = num % 2;
    binary = "" + digit + binary;
    num = parseInt(num / 2);
  }
  return binary;
}
console.log(decimalToBinary(5));
```

Comment: The OP was asking for an explanation for how their code converts the number from decimal to binary