# How to clear all current/pending AJAX requests

Tags: jquery

when users click certain links on my app it makes ajax requests... What I want to do is on every main click, abort all existing ajax requests either current or pending. Is this possible?

The reason why is requests are getting out of sync. Meaning if a user clicks on a project, which should load tasks. If they then click on another project, the first click's tasks are being populated.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stop all active ajax requests in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

Comment: Please stop writing tags in your question titles. You've done it to every single one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply keep a global variable which stores the most recent ajax request and then abort it before making the next request.

Answer (score -1):

When we abort an variable-cum-ajaxRequest using `variable.abort();` it is permanently disabled and cannot be used to create another request in the future.

So to avoid this we can use dynamic variables `window["var"+i]` and increase the value of i everytime  an new request is made.

Then at the time a request is to be cancelled use `window["var"+(i-1)].abort();`

Comment: The better answer is to use an array to store these requests rather than polluting the 'global' space.