# How should I stop a "in progress" jquery POST?

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, submit

I have a jQuery ajax post, where I upload big files with POST. I want to give to user the ability to cancel the submit, clicking a button, while the submit is in progress. How can I do this ?

Comment: You could use this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Answer (score 2):

```
var xhr = null;

xhr = $.ajax({
    url : 'www.example.com?some-large-call',
    success : function(responseText) {
        // some DOM manipulation
    }
});

$("#cancel").click(function() { xhr.abort() });
```

This should work for you

Comment: I use the .ajaxForm jquery plugin. I don't know how to access the xhr object.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1002-XMLHttpRequest-Object-Has-An-Abort-Method.htm) that explains the XMLHTTPRequest.Abort() method.  I believe that is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case you can try something like this

```
var isRequestCancelled = false;

isRequestCancelled = false;

$.post({ url:"", success:function{
   if(isRequestCancelled){
     //Alert the user with cancel message
   }
   else{
     //Confirm the user
   }
}
});

//Show a cancel buttons once you post to server and on cancel click set the global variable.

$(".cancel").click(function(){ isRequestCancelled = true;});
```

Comment: wouldn't this continue the "POST" ?

Comment: Yes it will. As I said it is to handle the worst case even after the post successfully happened but user cancelled it.

Comment: that is indeed worst case, because, in some cases you would need to send a "undo" to the server

Comment: Exactly we do need to handle such cases.