# Jquery On Click Function that Stops an Ajax Requests currently running

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stop all active ajax requests in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

I want to have a button that will abort any ajax requests currently being run. Below is a selector that grabs the right button. What should go in the place of the alert('test')?

```
$('#abort').click(function(){
     alert('test')
   });
```

Comment: You can find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery/446626

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call abort() method - on each of the ajax calls !

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'someurl',
    success: function(result){..........}
});
```

After that you can abort the request:

```
request.abort();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an array for each xhr object:

```
var xhrArray = new Array();
```

For every xhr object you need to add it to an array (where xhr is the object):

```
xhrArray.push(xhr);
```

Then on abort:

```
for( i = 0; i < xhrArray.length; i++){
        xhrArray[i].abort();
        stop = true;
    }
```

The stop variable is for a loop that is elsewhere in my code to prevent more xhr objects from being created/sent.