# AJAX calling being aborted before it is complete with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js, onbeforeunload

I've followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10701856/1591165) on how to abort all AJAX requests on page redirection. It basically uses ajaxSend to add the xhr request object to an array and then ajaxComplete to remove that object from the array and then if the page is redirected it will loop through that array and abort each request that the browser is still waiting for.

This works fine for all normal AJAX requests using $.ajax({}).  However, if a Backbone AJAX request is called like model.save() then the window.onbeforeunload function gets executed before anything happens and causes the model.save() to be aborted before it is event sent to the server.

Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this or why the window.onbeforeunload function is getting called?

Here is the code that I got from the linked answer:

```
var xhrPool = [];
$.xhrPool = {};
$.xhrPool.abortAll = function () {
   $.each(xhrPool, function (idx, jqXHR) {
       jqXHR.abort();
   });
   xhrPool.length = 0;
};

$(document).ajaxSend(function (e, jqXHR, options) {
   xhrPool.push(jqXHR);
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, jqXHR, options) {
   xhrPool = $.grep(xhrPool, function (x) {
       return x != jqXHR;
   });
});

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   $.xhrPool.abortAll();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

did you tried using the wait flag at the time to save?

like this
model.save(data,{wait:true});

Hope this helps.