# Make sure all async calls have been completed in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a webapp that is doing a bunch of async API calls using jQuery:s $.get and $.post methods.
I need to make sure that all these have finished successfully (HTTP status code 200) before I activate a button (display: none/block).

Is there a way to make sure that there are no outstanding async calls waiting out-of-the-box in jQuery? Or do I need to keep track of this myself?

I'm using jQuery v1.8.3.

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: You will need to keep track of this yourself.  It sounds to me like you expect that really, so I guess you have some idea how to do it.  Let us know if not :)

Comment: @NULL, thanks for noticing, edited the main post with this.

Comment: use ajax calls and - success: error: functions to set a variable for  each error... in the last call do a flag (variable) check when done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a "Master Deferred", which will only resolve when all of the other Deferreds (the AJAX requests) have completed successfully;

```
jQuery.when(jQuery.get('/foo'), jQuery.post('/bar'), jQuery.get('/baz')).done(function () {
    $('button').show();
});
```

The syntax is to pass each `Deferred` as a parameter to `jQuery.when()`, which returns a `Deferred` which resolves when one fails, or when all of them complete.

If you don't know beforehand how many AJAX requests you have, already have them in an array, or just don't want to use the above, you can use `Function.apply` like so;

```
var ajaxRequests = [jQuery.get('/foo'), jQuery.post('/bar'), jQuery.get('/baz')];

jQuery.when.apply(jQuery, ajaxRequests).done(function () {
    $('button').show();
});
```

For more info, see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when, or http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2014/01/tracking-joining-parallel-ajax-requests-with-jquery/ <sup>(my blog)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8841412/247893), you should be able to use the same code (you do not need the `abortAll` function, though, so it's been removed, and a check for active requests has been added):

```
$.xhrPool = [];
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
        $.xhrPool.push(jqXHR);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR) {
        var index = $.xhrPool.indexOf(jqXHR);
        if (index > -1) {
            $.xhrPool.splice(index, 1);
        }
        if ($.xhrPool.length > 0) {
            //There are still active requests - keep the button hidden
        } else {
            //There's no more active requests - show the button
        }
    }
});
```

This will work for all ajax requests requested through jQuery, both with `$.get`, `$.post` and `$.ajax`.

Comment: Why store `xhrPool` under the `$` namespace?

Comment: @NULL, I guess because you need to clear the array before checking it