# JQuery Mobile : Prevent changePage based on condition

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to prevent a page change based on a condition (result of a calculation or service call).

I have read below links but nothing works for me on iOS device (hybrid App).

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/7/19/Preventing-navigation-to-a-page-in-jQuery-Mobile
[Stop all active ajax requests in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery)
http://jsfiddle.net/kiliman/zMnUM/

my HTML looks like:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"> 
        <li><a href="#secondPage" Onclick='change(0)' id='secBtn'>Second Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="#thirdPage" Onclick='change(1)' id='thrBtn'>Third Page</a></li> 
</ul>
```

and in JS , I want to achieve similar:

```
function change(val) {
if(val == 1) {
    $.mobile.changePage("#thirdPage", { transition: "slide"});
}else {
    $(document).bind("pagebeforechange", function(e ,ob) {
if(ob.toPage && (typeof ob.toPage==="string") && ob.toPage.indexOf('page.html') >=   0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();             
    $.mobile.activePage.find('.ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-btn-active');
      }
    });
 }

}
```

Now when **e.preventDefault()** has been called then it stops all events on all buttons, links etc.

I want to only stop/run on a particular button, LI or item. I don't know how to achieve this.

Any suggestions please.