# How to interrupt reponse function on jQuery AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax function which takes some time to respond, due to large file. How do I interrupt the response function if I want to stop the Ajax request?

```
$("#startAjaxButton").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"ajaxRequest.txt",
      success:function(result){
         $("#div1").html(result);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: your question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: Alternatively, use `timeout` option within the `.ajax({})` object if it's over a specific time limit

Answer (score 2):

[Just use the `abort()` method.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#abort%28%29)

Like this:

```
var query = $.ajax({ ... });

// later...
query.abort();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the ajax request by using the `.abort()`,

```
 var xRequest = $.ajax({
    url:"ajaxRequest.txt",
      success:function(result){
         $("#div1").html(result);
      }
  });

 xRequest.abort();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to stop the ajax request.
Either you can use the `abort()` method like following

```
var xhr = jQuery.ajax({
 url : "/test",
 ...
});

   xhr.abort();
```

Or using the `timeout` option like following,

```
 - var xhr = jQuery.ajax({
        timeout : 3000,
        ...
       }
```

Also you can refer the following links, which are similar to this question

[abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

[How-to-Abort-a-AJAX-Call-Before-Calling-the-Same-A](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/573999/How-to-Abort-a-AJAX-Call-Before-Calling-the-Same-A)