# Stop ajax request

Tags: ajax

Consider I have 4 option like

1. display Name
2. display Age
3. display Address
4. display PhoneNo

On clicking of each option i am making an ajax request and pulling the appropriate details and displaying it. but the problem is for an instance i click on the `display Name` option the ajax request is sent immediately i click on the `display Age` option this triggers an ajax request and displays the data when the first request's response comes back it overwrites the data of the second request, So can i stop the previous ajax request(s). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes possible.

```
 var ajaxCall=$.ajax({
      -----
      ------
     });
```

then.You can use the following code, If you want reject of the ajax response

```
ajaxCall.abort()
```

Comment: Thanks, but if don't know the ajax request name like ("ajaxCall.abort()"  ) how to abort all requests globally.

Comment: this [link]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery may help you

Answer (score 1):

Use a variable to store a AJAX request:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'someurl',
    success: function(result){}
});
```

AND abort the request before you call again the same AJAX function:

```
request.abort();
```

You could use an array keeping track of all pending ajax requests and abort them if necessary.

Comment: upvote for the last statement 'use an array keeping track of all pending ajax..'