# Abort all async request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my page, I call 15 ajax request. Also I have a button which cancels all the pending ajax requests. [As per documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#abort()), abort() terminates the request if it has already been sent.

Now when I check my console, even after I click cancel button, I get some replies from ajax script (I guess those were already sent by the time I clicked that button). So how can I make sure no reply should come once I press cancel button?

[You can check the script here](http://mylibrarymanager.com/call.php) (couldn't use jsfiddle as not sure how to make ajax request).

**JS Code**

```
var xhrPool = [];

$(window).load(function(){
        callAjax1();
});

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
        xhrPool.push(jqXHR);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR) {
        var index = xhrPool.indexOf(jqXHR);
        if (index > -1) {
            xhrPool.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});

var abortAjax = function () {
    $.each(xhrPool, function(idx, jqXHR) {
        if(jqXHR && jqXHR .readystate != 4){
            jqXHR.abort();
        }
    });
    console.log("All pending cancelled"); // Should not have any ajax return after this point
    $.xhrPool = [];
};

$("#cancel-button").click(function (){
        abortAjax();
});


function callAjax2(ajaxcallid){
    console.log("Initiate ajax call " + ajaxcallid); // Should not have any ajax return after this point
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "test.php"
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        console.log(msg + ajaxcallid); // msg = "Ajax return for "
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
}

function callAjax1(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "test.php"
    })
    .done(function( msg ) {
        for(var i = 0; i < 15; i++){
            callAjax2(i);
        }
    })
    .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown);
    });
}
```

**Console Output:**
[image]

Comment: it's all the odd ones - perhaps your logic is wrong

Comment: That's interesting, I didn't notice. Though I am not sure where the logic can go wrong. The code is all that I posted. Inside test.php is only one line: "echo Ajax return for ".

Comment: 15 calls ... result 2 returned, 7 x abort, 6 x return after abort - numbers add up, something isn't right ... `console.log(xhrPool.slice())` at the top of the `abortAjax` function to see what's happening (the .slice is to get a snapshot)

Comment: refer these links http://jsfiddle.net/s4pbn/3/ second one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: @Jaromanda X .. added in the code. You can check the link http://mylibrarymanager.com/call.php

Comment: Yeah, it's always every second one does not abort - sometimes odd, sometimes even, but half the "aborts" are ignored!

Comment: @Arunprasanth KV .. I believe mine is identical to those examples ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$.each(xhrPool.slice(), function(idx, jqXHR) {
```

I think while you are aborting, some are returning, so the array gets messed up

this way you are working with a snapshot of the array

though, one or two may still sneak through due to timing of course

Comment: Interesting thing is, there are so many tutorial/examples over internet which i have been reading through all morning, and nobody used that slice() command. A big thumbs up for the catch.

Comment: I'm not sure I can explain it more than what I said in the answer. One way to test my theory is to put console.logs in the abort loop, and in the `complete: function` (again, use .slice to get a snapshot of the current state of the array), and observe the sequence of events as they unfold