# Reject all AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to immediately reject all AJAX requests depending on a variable. I understand how to hook the XMLHttpRequest but not sure how to reject it.

```
(function(open) {
            XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url, async, user, pass) {
                this.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
                    if(this.readyState === 1){
                        // stop all ajax attempts if we're disconnected
                        if(!self.isConnected){
                            console.log('rejecting')
                            // reject here
                            this.abort(); // ???
                        }
                    }
                }, false);
                open.call(this, method, url, async, user, pass);
            };
        })(XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open);
```

Also I want to know if calling this within
`this.readyState === 0` is akin to calling it "when the request first starts"

Answer (score 0):

you can use abort function to abort the ajax request, first save your request in some variable and call abort on it

```
$(document).ready(
    var xhr;

    var fn = function(){
        if(xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
            xhr.abort();
        }
        xhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax/progress.ftl',
            success: function(data) {
                //do something
            }
        });
    };

    var interval = setInterval(fn, 500);
);
```

There is another approach of creating AJAX Pool setup, which I don't recommend, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4pbn/3/) here

```
$.xhrPool = [];
$.xhrPool.abortAll = function() {
    $(this).each(function(idx, jqXHR) {
        jqXHR.abort();
    });
    $.xhrPool = [];
};

$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR) {
        $.xhrPool.push(jqXHR);
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR) {
        var index = $.xhrPool.indexOf(jqXHR);
        if (index > -1) {
            $.xhrPool.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I am interested in all requests

Comment: @Tester232323: then you need keep your all request in some array, and then you can call abort on them... you need to maintain a request variable

Comment: Is there no access to the browsers own xhr queue?

Comment: @Tester232323 : Not actually provided by browsers, secondly this will just ignore the response, it won't halt execution at the server at all

Comment: It looks like I can actually just call `this.abort()`

Comment: @Tester232323 : I have updated the answer and there is another example here aswell -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: @Tester232323: got it?

Comment: I put `this.abort()` and on the network tab of Chrome's tools the request never even starts, so I think that is sufficient.

Comment: I did upvote (i did not downvote). But I did not use your answer. All I did was add `this.abort()` and I did not need to use any arrays of requests.

Answer (score 0):

I simply added

`this.abort()`

and this seems to immediately abort all requests when desired.