# Stop ajax function before collapsible element close

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a collapsible element wherein an ajax is requested when the collapsible is opened. However, I also want to stop the ajax request before the collapsible is closed.

```
$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "check_active_operator.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(r)
        {
            if(r==1){
               //Operator is available

           }else if(r==0){
               //No operator available
           }
        }       
    });
});

$(".collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    // STOP AJAX REQUEST
});
```

NOTE: I also have this ajax request on check_active_operator.php. That request must be aborted as well if the collapsible is closed. As of now, it is still running when the collapsible is closed.

```
function getMessages(){
    var getchatroomid = $.trim($("#chatroomid").val());
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "messages.php",
        data: {getchatroomid},
        cache: false,
        success: function(data)
        {
        $(".chatMessages").html(data);
        } 
    });
}

setInterval(function(){
    getMessages();
    var c = $('.chatMessages');
    c.scrollTop(c.prop("scrollHeight")); //scroll down
}, 1000); //half a second
```

Comment: Please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Comment: Cache the ``$.ajax`` by declaring the variable outside, defining it inside the ``show`` event, and then aborting it inside the ``hide`` event.

Comment: Or this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery ... you can just assign the ajax request to a variable and call the `abort()` method on it in the hide.bs.collapse function

Comment: `.abort()` should do the trick. [Read More](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/abort-ajax-requests-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can use abort function like this

```
var xhr;
$(".collapse").on('show.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    xhr = $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: "check_active_operator.php",
        cache: false,
        success: function(r)
        {
            if(r==1){
               //Operator is available

           }else if(r==0){
               //No operator available
           }
        }       
    });
});

$(".collapse").on('hide.bs.collapse', function(e) {
    xhr.abort();
});
```

Comment: By the way, I also have an ajax request inside check_active_operator.php. I tried your answer but it does not abort the ajax request inside it.

Comment: can you provide fiddle link?