# Cannot read property 'abort' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to cancel all remaining AJAX requests if the length of an input field is empty. However, I am seeing this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'abort' of undefined

```
$("input#enter").keyup(function() {
    if(this.value.length < 1) {
        $("#display").empty();
        request.abort(); // <--- this line
    }else{ 
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getdata.php",
            data: "title=" + this.value,
            success: function(data) {
                $("#display").empty(); 
                $("#display").html(data);
            }
        });
    } 
});
```

This is where I saw a similar example and they used `request.abort()`: [Stop all active ajax requests in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802936/stop-all-active-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

Comment: Because you're trying to call a method on a variable you haven't defined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is due to the scope of the `request` variable. You need to declare it outside of the handler:

```js
var request;

$("input#enter").keyup(function() {
  var $display = $('#display');
  if (this.value.trim().length < 1) {
    $display.empty();
    request && request.abort();
  } else {
    request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getdata.php",
      data: { title: this.value.trim() },
      success: function(data) {
        $display.html(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Note that I amended the JS code slightly, as you don't need to call `empty()` if you're overwriting the `html()` anyway.

Also, assuming this is a kind of filtering system, you may want to consider using `abort()` on `request` in all instances, as if a new key has been pressed then the previous request is no longer relevant to the results and can be ended - something like this:

```
var request;

$("input#enter").keyup(function() {
  var $display = $('#display');
  request && request.abort(); // always abort the previous request, if there was one

  if (this.value.trim().length > 0) {
    request = $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "getdata.php",
      data: { title: this.value.trim() },
      success: function(data) {
        $display.html(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it seems the outstanding AJAX calls still run as it shows in the network console tab

Comment: I just updated to add a note about that. You seem to be only aborting the request when a value was typed but then deleted. It would make more sense to *always* abort the previous request, then make a new one only if a value of appropriate length was typed.

Comment: Yes that may be a better idea. Should I place the abort function inside the keyup function?

Comment: Is it more beneficial to use `trim()`?

Comment: The code doesn't seem to be having any effect on my site and it still runs every request even when a new one is made

Comment: Ah i fixed it, simple typo on my end. Thank you!