# Is it possible to enable/disable JavaScript in web browser using PHP?

Tags: javascript

A client web browser has JavaScript enabled, but I want to emulate the state where JavaScript is disabled to run code within `noscript` tags. For example: on the site is a button - "No JavaScript". When the client clicks the button, the code within nonscript tags will execute. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can not control whether the user has JavaScript enabled in their browser or not, so although you could potentially throw a JavaScript error to maybe stop execution (see: [Is it possible to stop JavaScript execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution)) you won't be able to disable it and cause the noscript tag content to display without disabling JavaScript in your browser.