# How to terminate earlier a MongoDb shell script?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

Writing:

```
if (...) {
    return;
}
```

in a MongoDb shell script will complain: `SyntaxError: return not in function`

I have also tried the `exit` mongo console command:

```
if (...) {
    exit;
}
```

but you get the error: `ReferenceError: exit is not defined`

How can one earlier terminate the execution in the `js` script file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In mongodb you can use the `quit()` function as documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/reference/method/quit/).  While it's not documented well, I did a quick test and can return a non zero exit code by doing `quit(1)` which will exit w/ status 1.

Comment: Beware if you're about to try it in Robomongo. It will close whole application immediately. [Tested on OSX, Robomongo 1.0.0-RC1]

Comment: Happened to me @ŁukaszMazan, I read your comment right after it closed -.-

Answer (score 6):

I have used the following solution:

```
(function(){

    // now you can use the return keyword anywhere:
    if (/* some condition */) {
        print("This is an error condition");
        return;
    }

})();
```

I know that terminating the script this way will not make `mongo` return an error code different than 0 (as the accepted solution does).

Answer (score 3):

After some searching on the topic it seems the preferred way to stop javascript execution with an `exit` like statement is to actually throw something: [Is it possible to stop JavaScript execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution) , this question is either the most common example or the only one in my view that would reasonably work.