# Custom confirm box in JQuery that returns a boolean value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using JQuery & JQuery UI and I tried using JQuery UI Dialog to solve this problem but I was unable to accomplish it.

Basically I have for example this code that uses JS confirm box:

```
// if user presses cancel, do not proceed to the next section of the code
if ( ! confirm('Are you sure you want to press OK?')) {
  return;
}

.... Lots of code below
```

I want to turn this to use a custom box that I can customize using CSS. I tried with UI dialog:

```
function confirmIt(text) {
   $('#confirm_dialog').dialog({
      width: 300,
      height: 150,
      buttons: {
         "OK": function() { return true; },
         "Cancel": function() { return false; }
      }
   });
}

if ( ! confirmIt('Are you sure you want to press OK?')) {
   return;
}
.... Lots of code below
```

Now the problem with above code is that a lot of code below the if condition still executes. I understand that JQuery Dialog is aync process, but I was wondering if there are such plugins for free out there that I could use that will return boolean value? Basically functionality wise it should work exactly same as JS `confirm()`. I do not want to wrap that a lot of code within the callback of JQuery UI dialog to achieve this. I just want to **stop** script execution if `CANCEL is clicked` and **continue** execution if `OK is clicked`.

Comment: That's not possible in that way cause these dialogs have "callbacks" which get called on certain actions (clicking OK for instance). The native methods `prompt`, `alert`, and `confirm` will wait for a user input and pause the script execution

Comment: @revaxarts there is no way to pause the script execute similar to what JS native methods do ?

Comment: I've explained it in my answer with a possible solution

Comment: Regarding your deleted question just now, consider asking about Masters courses in one of the SO chatrooms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's not possible to stop script execution ([except for debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution#answer-9298915)) you should alter your method:

```
function confirmIt(text, okFunc, cancelFunc) {
   $('#confirm_dialog').dialog({
      width: 300,
      height: 150,
      buttons: {
         "OK": okFunc && okFunc,
         "Cancel": cancelFunc && cancelFunc
      }
   });
}

confirmIt('Are you sure you want to press OK?', function(){
    .... Lots of code below
}, function(){
    ...function on cancel (which can be empty)
});
```

so if you haven't any action on the cancel button just use

```
confirmIt('Are you sure you want to press OK?', function(){
    .... Lots of code below
});
```

or

```
confirmIt('Are you sure you want to press OK?', confirmFunction);

function confirmFunction(){
    .... Lots of code below
}
```

Comment: `okFunc && okFunc()` -> `okFunc && okFunc` or simply `okFunc`

Comment: I see, that is what I had in mind. I wanted to try to avoid putting "lots of code" within a confirmIt function but I guess there is no other way. Thanks for your answer buddy. +1

Comment: @KevinB `okFunk && okFunc()` will execute `okFunc`only if it exists. `okFunk && okFunk` would simple return true (if defined) but wouldn't execute `okFunc`. Ok? ;)

Comment: @GGio you can avoid the anonymous function with `confirmIt('Are you sure you want to press OK?', confirmFunction)` to move the code in a dedicate method. I've updated my answer

Comment: @revaxarts my point is you're executing the function immediately rather than passing it to be executed later when the button is clicked.