# Why don't we exit/die a script after redirect in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, exit

We need to do `exit;` after redirect in php because `exit;` doesn't stop the rest of the code from running.
But why we don't do something like that in javascript.
I want to do something like

```
if(window.location.replace("http://something.com")){
  return;
}
```

or

```
window.location.replace("http://something.com");
throw "stop the execution.";
```

Do i need to do that ? 
If not why?

Comment: Just reference [Is it possible to stop JavaScript execution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution)

Comment: Because javascript doesn't do a redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Why we need to do `exit();` after the redirection in php?

When you do

```
header( "Location: ./somepage.php" );
```

As [`php manual on header says`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php), *header() is used to send a raw HTTP header*. So it doesnt stop the script from executing further. It sends the response header related to redirection back to browser and continues executing the code below that. So `exit()` would prevent doing that.

#### Do we need `return;` after the window.location calls?

The JS code says the browser to navigate to another url. So when the navigation is done. The browser navigates to new page and the code below the `window.location` will not be executed unlike the php behaviour explained above. So we dont require it.