# How to 'return' outside function definition in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, userscripts, tampermonkey

1. I need to rewrite my tampermonkey script on typescript.
2. What is correct way to rewrite this javascript on typescript?

   ```
   if (window.top != window.self ) {
       return;
   }
   ```

Main goal is to stop executing script if it's running not in window.top.

Typescript compiler write ERROR TS1108: A 'return' statement can only be used within a function body.

Comment: We are missing some code here, but could your code be wrap inside a class or a function. That function could them be called from the main execution.

Comment: This code works on javascript outside all classes and functions - it's stop execution of script and looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/4tfjvvxk/

Answer (score -4, accepted):

You cannot return outside function, but using throw Exception you can stop execution userscipts (tampermonkey) too:

```
if (window.top != window.self) {
    throw new Error("Not on top");
}
```

Comment: No!  Don't throw errors for things that are standard OP procedure.  In addition to inducing future head scratching, this also will (very slightly) degrade browser performance unnecessarily.  Wrap the whole main part of your userscript in an `if()` as David Laberge shows in his (edited) answer.

Comment: I cannot use inverse logic as David show, because declare some modules after return.

And module declaration cannot be into if.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would do it. Typescript transpile into Javascript, but it is not Javascript.

```
if(validateIfTop()){

    // MAIN BODY OF YOUR USERSCRIPT GOES HERE

}

validateIfTop():boolean{
    return window.top === window.self;
}
```

That should fix the current transpiler error. But it is possible that your code you have run fine in is current state. It's just that it does not make sense to return a value out of the main script. You might want to have a look to this question : [Is it possible to stop JavaScript execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution) It explain how to stop a javascript script.

Comment: As I said 'return' in my example - stop userscript. Your example - not

Comment: But thanks for link to stop JavaScript execution, I rewrite script with throw exception.

Comment: There was a logic inversion in this answer, but the approach is otherwise correct for GM/TM/User scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your original JS functions only conincidently, i.e. it fails silently at runtime:

[image]

I would refactor the code to be surrounded by an `if` block as already suggested by David.

Comment: No it doesn't fail.  The OP's code is perfectly valid *in a userscript*. He just wants to preprocess it with Typescript -- where it gives the indicated error.