# Prevent Script from loading normally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a Chrome Extension for a webpage. The page has a script execute which changes the way the page is displayed by removing or emptying elements.
I found the `<script>` tag that I need to delete or stop from executing. Is there a way to load the page into memory, parse it remove the `<script>` tag and then load normally?

The only way I can remove the code via Javascript as of yet is to use Chrome Inspector to disable Javascript and then run the following code.

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
   for (i=0, max=scripts.length; i < max; i++){
      var currentS = scripts[i];
      var xInner = currentS.innerHTML;
      if (xInner.indexOf('jsMenu1') < 1){
          currentS.parentNode.removeChild(currentS);
      }
   }
```

Comment: You could take a look at this possibly but I'm not sure if it would completely fix your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution

Comment: Can you in any way alter the given `<script>` in question? (you could possibly apply `defer` attribute to it and thus remove the script without it executing)

Comment: @mattfetz unfortunately that did not work.

Answer (score -1):

Strange Request. This will work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var $html = $('html');
   var $script = $html.find('script#scriptToRemove');
   $script.remove();

   var htmlStr = $html.html();
   $html.html(htmlStr);
});
```

Comment: I don't think so, as in `ready` the script you're removing has already been executed

Comment: I do think so, this was tried and tested. This reloads the page with the appropriate content.

Comment: If the requirement is to not see the initial content, simply add css body { display: none } until after this script has executed.