# How to stop form from submitting after failing validation.

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I've been working on this form and have come to a roadblock. I'm trying to stop the form from submitting if it fails validation. The form itself is using formspree.io to collect the results and email them. I set out to write this in all js.

I think that because of this adding return false to the end of any validation does not work because formspree is doing something extra that I am not aware of/ don't understand.

Here is my code without the form elements but just validation logic and submit button. You can look at all the code for the form [here](http://codepen.io/alaw989/pen/mOqoYK?editors=0010).Any help or hints or direction would be appreciated thanks.

```
var app = document.createElement('form');
app.name = 'formIT'
app.action = "https://formspree.io/alaw989@gmail.com"
app.method = "POST"

//all div elements and stuff used to build the form would be here//

var submit = document.createElement('button'); 
submit.textContent = 'Submit'
app.appendChild(submit)
submit.style.cssText = "display: block; margin: 40px 0px 0px 20px; background-color: #1DA2F5; border: none; color: white; padding: 16px 32px; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer;"
submit.type = "submit"
submit.value = "Send"

submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
   var x = emailInput.value;
   var atpos = x.indexOf("@");
   var dotpos = x.lastIndexOf(".");
     if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=x.length) {
        alert("Not a valid e-mail address");
    }

  var yes1 = radio1a.checked;
  var no1 = radio1b.checked;

  if (yes1 == "" && no1 == "") {
    alert("Please answer question 1")
  }

  var yes2 = radio2a.checked;
  var no2 = radio2b.checked;

  if (yes2 == "" && no2 == "") {
    alert("Please answer question 2")    
  }

  var yes3 = radio3a.checked;
  var no3 = radio3b.checked;

  if (yes3 == "" && no3 == "") {
    alert("Please answer question 3")    
  }

  var yes4 = radio4a.checked;
  var no4 = radio4b.checked;

  if (yes4 == "" && no4 == "") {
    alert("Please answer question 4")    
  }

  var yes5 = radio5a.checked;
  var no5 = radio5b.checked;

  if (yes5 == "" && no5 == "") {
    alert("Please answer question 5")    
  }

  var yes6 = radio6a.checked;
  var no6 = radio6b.checked;

  if (yes6 == "" && no6 == "") {
    alert("Please answer question 6")    
  }

   var a = input1.value
   var b = input2.value
   if (a === "") {
    alert("Missing Question 7")
   }
   if (b === "") {
     alert("Missing Question 8")
   }

});
```

Comment: Looks like I may have just figured out by adding a .required to the radio button elements. This seems to be a pretty good solution unless anyone had any better ideas. edit: seems like this may even eliminate the need for the all the if/else statements.

Answer (score 0):

For your question, I would recommend using an error-catching function or similar, which would kill the script on errors.

Check out the answer: [Is it possible to stop JavaScript execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var form = document.getElementById('form-id');

  event.preventDefault();

  // validations here

  if (validationsPassed) form.submit()
});
```

Comment: Where is validationsPassed defined here or is that something you are leaving up to me to do ?

Comment: exactly, you just have to move your validations there

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your radio button "checked" events should be checking for true/false not " ". Second, you have two options. You could add e in your click event and add e.preventDefault() as Matias suggested:

```
submit.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Or add a function to validate form in your form tag:

```
<form onsubmit="validateForm();">
```