# Stop Javascript click event execution if condition is satisfied

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm trying to stop execution of Javascript event handler when some condition is satisfied, and my code looks like this:

```
 $(".save").click(function (event) {
            $(".loader").fadeIn(300);

            var statusValue = $("#status").val();
            console.log(statusValue);

            if (statusValue == null || statusValue == '') {
                $("#status").css({
                    "border-color": "red",
                    "border-width": "1px",
                    "border-style": "solid"
                });
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log("NOT EXECUTED");
            }

            console.log("EXECUTED");
// .. some more code
}
```

When I check console I'm getting results like this:

> null
> null
> NOT EXECUTED
> EXECUTED

So I'm wondering how come?
`If == null` condition is satisfied shouldn't `event.preventDefault()` stop this `.click` event from execution till end?

I'm trying to achieve, if nothing is selected in  then prevent execution, my select looks like this:

```
<select class="form-control" id="status">
        <option value="Done">Done</option>
        <option value="Complited">Completed</option>
        <option value="Cancel">Cancel</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't think `event.preventDefault()` does what you think it does

Comment: In your select, Done is selected by default

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` doesn't work like that. read this for more info,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

The event is already happening. 
You can use this:

```
 $('form').attr('onsubmit', 'return false;');
```

Answer (score 0):

No, `event.preventDefault()` doesn't do what you're thinking, in this case if you want to stop the function execution you can just but a empty `return;` at the end of the `if` block. Another solution is put an `else` block.

`event.preventDefault()` prevents the default action to happen, for an example, if you put it on a `<a>link</a>` it won't redirects to the `href`, because the default of a click on a `a` is to redirect the page to the path on `href` prop. [Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JvJgXz).

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` does not work in your case, use `return;` instead

```js
$(".save").click(function (event) {

    if (true) {
      console.log("EXECUTED");
      return;
      console.log("NOT EXECUTED");
    }

    console.log("NOT EXECUTED");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="banner-message">
  <button class="save">Save</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop it use this:

```
throw new Error("Something went badly wrong!");
```

source:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9298915/4110122