# Is there a way to stop v8 on chrome from executing javascript after the onload event is fired?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, v8

It necessarily doesn't have to be after the `onload` event, but basically at any point during or after the page load can I stop v8 from executing any further javascript using some runtime chrome flag or javascript internal flag?

Comment: You might want to look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550574/how-to-terminate-the-script-in-javascript), which have already covered this topic at length.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to terminate the script in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550574/how-to-terminate-the-script-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

For debugging: open DevTools, switch to the "Sources" tab, click the "Pause" button on the right.

If you want to interrupt earlier than you can click manually, you can also set a breakpoint on the line of interest and reload the page.

If debugging is not your purpose, please be more specific.