# How to stop all the scripts in a page in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with the fact that the flow of control in javascript is not what I'm used to. Not linear. Sometimes when I test I get the error message "A script is slowing down your browser" at times when everything should be stopped.

I spend ages looking for the bug. This time it was something really silly, a variable which stopped the function when it reached 350 px. Then I added a way to change the speed and sometimes this variable was incremented by 3 at each step. So it never reached 350, it went from 348 to 351.

So I was wondering if there was a "STOP!" command. Something which would leave the display of the web page in its current state but stop all running processes?

Comment: The answer is: No

Comment: you should fix the logic, there is nothing prevent you from `return`

Answer (score 6):

Debugger? It just creates a breakpoint, where you can analyse what's going on right now. I know it's not exactly what you're asking about, but it could work for your use case.

---

#### Usage

`debugger;`

Can be used from within console too.

---

#### Learn more

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_debugging.asp

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger

Comment: I recommend adding a semicolon after the debugger statement because of best practices. In addition, it also helps people recognize that it's a statement. Simply saying `debugger` might not make anything click in someone's head, but adding a semicolon can be the tipping point that makes the last puzzle piece fall in place and makes that person go "a-ha!".

Also note that (at least for chrome) debugger will only work when the console is opened.

Comment: I was about to comment that it only works with the console open. I would really love something that could simply freeze the page in it's current state and stop any further scripts from executing. In the console->preferences->debugger->Disable Javscript checkbox does just what I want except it's a PITA to get to.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want here, the main answer is "no".

There *are* a few "hacks" (but they are quite intrusive and unreliable).

A good one (like mentioned in another answer here) is to throw the statement `debugger;` (that's all). Example:

```
let eggCount = 0;
function makeEggs(eggCount){
  //Stop! The user is eating too much!!!
  if(eggCount > 5){
    debugger;
  }
  else{
    make_egg("Over-hard");
    return eggCount++;
  }
}
```

However, this only works (or at least for chrome) if the console is open.

The second big one is to throw an error in your script (as shown by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9298915/14409978) post). It's hacky, and you can't have any `try...catch` loops (if you do then you have to throw an error, so you'd to re-throw that error).

```
let eggCount = 0;
function makeEggs(eggCount){
  //Stop! The user is eating too much!!!
  if(eggCount > 5){
    throw "Egg overflow!";
  }
  else{
    make_egg("Sunny side up");
    return eggCount++;
  }
}
```

The last big thing you can do (as mentioned by a comment here) is to re-write your logic.

From the looks of it, you have something like this:

```
let eggCount = 0;
function makeEggs(eggCount){
  //Stop! The user is eating too much!!!
  if(eggCount === 5){
    throw "STOP!"
  }
  else{
    make_egg("Over-hard");
    return eggCount++;
  }
}
```

Well, what if we did this?

```
eggCount = makeEggs(eggCount);
eggCount = 6;
eggCount = makeEggs(eggCount);
```

Since the equals sign checks for if it's just *five*, you can always *bypass* it.

This isn't a good idea, so we can re-wire our logic to do this instead:

```
let eggCount = 0;
function makeEggs(eggCount){
  //Stop! The user is eating too much!!!
  if(eggCount >= 5){
    throw "STOP!"
  }
  else{
    make_egg("Over-hard");
  }
}
```

Now it will stop if it's 5 *or greater*.

This:

```
eggCount = makeEggs(eggCount);
eggCount = 6;
eggCount = makeEggs(eggCount);
```

will still throw the "STOP" error, even though it's **greater than 5**.

Sometimes, it's as simple as re-writing your logic.

You don't need the big hack-y stuff if it's as simple as just making your program smarter ;)

I've ran into this type of problem before.

I haven't encountered an incident yet where re-writing my logic doesn't help!