# Is there a shortcut for the disable JavaScript checkbox in Chrome->DevTools->Settings?

Tags: javascript

Apparently there's no way in JavaScript to pause stop disable third party scripts from running (except maybe typing `debugger;` which isn't really convenient or useful with the overlay. If that's not true, please tell how), but for productivity's sake, is there some way to shortcut the functionality of the  disable Javascript checkbox in Chrome->DevTools->Settings?

Disabling javascript globally isn't helpful because the page needs to render before I pause it.

The following don't work for this specific need:

- [Is it possible to stop JavaScript execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution)
- [How to terminate the script in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550574/how-to-terminate-the-script-in-javascript)
- `debugger` because it blocks up the view of the page with an overlay

[image: Chrome DevTools Debugger Disable Javascript]

Comment: No, it's a __user preference__, it's not reasonable to get accessed by arbitrary web pages.

Comment: Me, as a user wants to click a shortcut and disble javsacript. Some kind of key mapping could be great. It's not for me to inject unless I could as an extension. I previously made an extension that loads pages without javscript which bypasses `noscript` but still needs to reload the page.

Comment: But the code to disable the JS is executed on an arbitrary web page, and if you can trigger such a code, what would prevent an arbitrary web page to trigger it on its own too?

Comment: I'm asking for a chrome setting or button, or keymapping and I'm willing to settle for something I can put in an extension. I'd even accept an alternate browser with a shortcut to kill Javascript mid-execution. What are you talking about?

Comment: You didn't mention anything about extensions in your question ...

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion and that I didn't communicate clearly. The question is 'Is there a shortcut for the disable JavaScript checkbox in Chrome->DevTools->Settings?'