# Starting newly-inserted <script> after AJAX call and stopping removed <script> after another AJAX call

Tags: javascript, ajax, eval, innerhtml

I'm doing a toy library in which the user can modify the DOM with AJAX, basically around:

```
fetch("/newpage").then(r => r.text()).then(html => {
    var tmp = document.createElement('html');
    tmp.innerHTML = html;
    document.querySelector("#container").outerHTML = tmp.querySelector("#container").outerHTML; 
                                                                        // insert in the DOM
```

The user of the library can decide to have `<script>` blocks in the inserted HTML `<div>`, so after insertion I do:

```
for (const scr of document.querySelectorAll("#container script"))
    eval(scr.innerHTML);
```

as discussed in [Executing <script> injected by innerHTML after AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-injected-by-innerhtml-after-ajax-call).

This works fine. But then, **if another AJAX call is done and `#container` is replaced again by something else, and the `<script>` is removed**, we need to be able to stop all running scripts *that originated from the `<script>` inside `#container`*.
**How to do this?**

Example:

- after AJAX call #1, `#container` contains a `<script>` with code running periodically (`setInterval`, etc.). It is now running thanks to `eval` (see above)
- after AJAX call #2, `#container` is replaced by something else, and this `<script>` is **no longer here**. But the `setInterval` task is still running... How to automatically kill this when `<script>` disappears after AJAX call #2?

Ideas: could we associate the return value of `eval(..)` to a variable, so that we can keep track of this, and kill its execution later?
Or when inserting `<script>` with `element.outerHTML = ...`, should we add an identifier (id or class) to the `<script>`, so that we can later take action on the code that this script block launched?

Note: neither [Is it possible to stop JavaScript execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298839/is-it-possible-to-stop-javascript-execution) nor [How to terminate the script in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550574/how-to-terminate-the-script-in-javascript) nor [Executing <script> injected by innerHTML after AJAX call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4619668/executing-script-injected-by-innerhtml-after-ajax-call) solve this question.

Comment: Good question. You need a new JavaScript context on the second mount. I don't know if this is possible.

Comment: I don't think what you are asking for, is possible. The script element is only the "vehicle" to transport the code - after the code has been parsed, the existence of the script element isn't of any relevance any more. You can not "undo" JavaScript execution, by removing the script element afterwards.

Comment: @CBroe Yes, this makes sense. It would be interesting to see how libraries do, for example [HTMX](https://htmx.org/) or [Unpoly](https://unpoly.com/): they do easy insertion of new DOM elements (including scripts!) with just HTML attributes (with JS and AJAX techniques), and they are able to start new `script` when inserted, and stop them when the HTML containing the `<script>` is removed in a later AJAX call. I tried reading the code of the latter, but I couldn't exactly find this part.

Comment: Instead of populating the `#container` element inside the main document, you could perhaps do this stuff inside in iframe? Then you could throw the iframe content away, and all script execution that happened (or still happens) inside the iframe, should be gone as well. (And if you use a simple assignment to `srcdoc` to populate the iframe, then I think you don't even need to jump thru extra `eval` hoops to get the script elements to execute.)

Comment: The real answer is DO NOT USE EVAL. Build a correct system that does not rely on eval.

Comment: Which general solution would you use here @epascarello?

Comment: @CBroe No, I prefer to not use iframe. The goal is to be able to have a lightweight website with AJAX requests for navigation, so I prefer avoid iframes for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap around the `setTimeout` before `eval()` the script. When removed the script, you can unregister the tasks.

```js
function mockInternal() {
    const setTimeout = window.setTimeout;
    const setInterval = window.setInterval;
    // window.setImmediate
    // window.addEventListener

    const setTimeoutHandlers = [];
    const setIntervalHandlers = [];

    window.setTimeout = function mock_setTimeout(callback, delay) {
        const h = setTimeout(callback, delay);
        setTimeoutHandlers.push(h);
        return h;
    }

    window.setInterval = function mock_setInterval(callback, delay) {
        const h = setInterval(callback, delay);
        setIntervalHandlers.push(h);
        return h;
    }

    return function clearMockInternal() {
        window.setTimeout = setTimeout;
        window.setInterval = setInterval;
        setTimeoutHandlers.forEach(h => clearTimeout(h));
        setIntervalHandlers.forEach(h => clearInterval(h));
    }
}

const clearMockInternal = mockInternal();
eval(`setInterval(() => console.log(new Date()), 1000);`);

setTimeout(() => {
    clearMockInternal();
    console.log("should not log Date from now");
}, 6000);
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer just answer your one question(for interval) but I just wanna share it. You can return values from your eval and use it for later. For example:

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="run1()">Run first method</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="run2()">Run second method</button>
    <div id="container">
    </div>
    <script>
        var pro1, pro2;
        function run1() {
            if (pro2 != undefined && pro2 != null) {
                clearInterval(pro2);
            }
            fetch("page1.html").then(r => r.text()).then(html => {
                var tmp = document.createElement('html');
                tmp.innerHTML = html;
                document.querySelector("#container").outerHTML = tmp.querySelector("#container").outerHTML;
                for (const scr of document.querySelectorAll("#container script")) {
                    pro1 = eval(scr.innerHTML);
                }
            });
        }
        function run2() {
            if (pro1 != undefined && pro1 != null) {
                clearInterval(pro1);
            }
            fetch("page2.html").then(r => r.text()).then(html => {
                var tmp = document.createElement('html');
                tmp.innerHTML = html;
                document.querySelector("#container").outerHTML = tmp.querySelector("#container").outerHTML;
                for (const scr of document.querySelectorAll("#container script")) {
                    var data = eval(scr.innerHTML);
                    pro2 = data;
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

page1.html

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

            <script>
                test();
                function test() {
                    var i = 0;
                    const interval =
                        setInterval(function () {
                            console.log(i);
                            i++;
                        }, 1000);
                    return interval;
                };
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">

            <script>
                test();
                function test() {
                    var i = 9999;
                    const interval =
                        setInterval(function () {
                            console.log(i);
                            i--;
                        }, 1000);
                    return interval;
                };
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Everytime you clicked a button it will stop other interval

Screenshot for sample:

[image: Sample]

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! How would you use this in the general case (could be setInterval or anything else, used by the user of the library)?

Comment: @Basj  you can use this with interval and xhrRequest all you need is return what you need (like if you want to stop timer return interval or if you wanna abort ajax or xhrrequest assign your request to a variable and return it.) I think You can write your own library but there will be limit what you can do. You should find something else than eval. I hope I can explain it.