# PHP's exit; in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the equivalent of PHP's exit; in Javascript/jQuery?

I need to stop my script early depending on certain conditions... The only answers I could find from search was stopping forms from submitting...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to terminate the script in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550574/how-to-terminate-the-script-in-javascript)

Comment: In PHP, exit() can be called anywhere. In JavaScript, return can only be called in a function, not in file scope.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try:

```
throw "stop execution";
```

Using return you will skip the current function, that's why throwing is more similar to PHP exit();

Comment: When I tried this I got an "uncaught exception" error. In PHP, I believe, exit() stops without error.

Answer (score 3):

I would finish a function early with a return statement:

```
return;
```

Comment: Only skipped the function and some of the script still ran for me.

Answer (score 2):

A javascript function is terminated by calling `return`. Usually you will be in the context of a function or something. Also event handlers (like for `onclick` on an element) will behave like a function and accept return.

Answer (score 1):

From looking on your certain problem, and for everyone else. Please see this.
This MIGHT help you.

Just put this one line

`if(exit_condition!=true)`

and also this requires your codes to be inside of

`$(document).ready()`

```
if(exit_condition!=true)
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // Your code
      // Your code
      // Your code
      // Your code
    });
```

I have also encountered this issue, @Jamesking56 has encountered. And this is my solution.