# how to stop execution with return false in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, boolean, return

i have the fallowing example:

```
<input type="button" id="create_account" value="Save">

var Misc = {
    validateForm: function () {
        if(x == 1){
            return false;
        }
        // this is a simplified example, but sometimes x != 1 and there is no return
    }
}

$(document).on('click', '#create_account', function() {
    Misc.validateForm();
    alert('continue');
});
```

the issue i'm having is that i get `continue`, even though i return false.

what i would like to happen is to run the alert only if `Misc.validateForm();` doesn't return anything

any ideas on this issue?

Comment: flow doesn't stop just because you return false, it would be like saying, `false; alert('continue')`, still gonna alert.

Comment: I guess you could [`stop()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/550583/2344142), but that's just silly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (Misc.validateForm() !== false) {
    alert('continue');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to

```
$(document).on('click', '#create_account', function() {
    if(Misc.validateForm() === false){
        return;
    }
    alert('continue');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are returning false but that does not determine that execution stops.  You should use something along the lines of:

```
if (!Misc.validateForm()) {
    alert('continue');
}
```

Comment: yes, i figure that much (witch is a bit different), the idea was to use `Misc.validateForm()` to either stop or continue the script. but thanks