# stop promise chain with multiple catches

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

In Node.js, I need to read a file and validate it's contents, all in async. I m using **Node.js 6.6**, **bluebird 3.4.6**

Example code:

```js
// pseudo function to read file contents - resolves when 'flag' is true, rejects when 'flag' is false.
function readFile(flag) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log('Reading file...');
        if (flag) {
            resolve('File contents');
        } else {
            reject('readFile error');
        }
    });
}

// pseudo function to validate file contents - resolves when 'flag' is true, rejects when 'flag' is false.
function validate(fileContents, flag) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log('Validating file: ', fileContents);
        if (flag) {
            resolve('Validate passed');
        } else {
            reject('validation failed');
        }
    });
}


readFile(false)
    .then(function (fileContents) {
        console.log('Successfully read the file:', fileContents);
        return fileContents;
    })
    .catch(function (fileReadErr) {
        console.log('Failed to read the file:', fileReadErr);
        throw fileReadErr; // or, return Promise.reject(err);
    })
    .then(function (fileContents) {
        return validate(fileContents, false);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log('Successfully validated the file:', result);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Failed to validate the file:', err);
    })
    ;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.4.6/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```

The above code will print

```
Reading file...
Failed to read the file: readFile error
Failed to validate the file: readFile error
```

The above promise chain roughly translates to below sync code:

```
try {
    let fileContents;

    try {
        fileContents = readFile(false);
        console.log('Successfully read the file:', fileContents);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Failed to read the file:', e);
        throw e;
    }

    let validationResult = validate(fileContents, false);
    console.log('Successfully validated the file:', validationResult);
} catch (err) {
    console.log('Failed to validate the file:', err);
}
```

And, throwing or rejecting in the first `catch` method **will still invoke the 2nd `catch` method**.

**My question**: Is there any way to break the chain once the file reading is failed? My objective is to return different HTTP status codes (file read error: 500, validation failed: 400) from an express.js route.

*I know a solution using non-standard specialized `catch` method, but that requires special handling. In the sense, I need to throw errors or need some filtering key in the error object and both of which are not in my hands, and involves some work to achieve it. This solution is mentioned in bluebird docs & here: [Handling multiple catches in promise chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076511/handling-multiple-catches-in-promise-chain)*

Comment: For those who want to mark this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076511/handling-multiple-catches-in-promise-chain, I want to know any other possible solution and like wise I don't want to handle all the errors in one `catch` at the end of chain as mentioned by @Esailija (bluebird author) here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26077569/340290

Comment: Given the constraints to your question, the answer is probably "No, there is no way to break a catch chain". What's the objection to using a final catch handler at the end of the chain?

Comment: To use `catch` at the end, at least I need to maintain a flag or have to verify the error object to know different error states. It'll become if-elseif-else kind. Isn't it?

Comment: Correct. Another option would be to use Babel and `async`/`await` or an async generator library like [co](https://github.com/tj/co)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I m currently looking at. More or less I need this functionality: http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution by far is to use what I call "insulated catches". ie, a pattern in which each `.catch()` is a specialist, associated with a particular step in the overall process, and the main chain comprises only .thens (and eventually a single, terminal catch).

Also, it is useful in this kind of circumstance to convey added information down the error path by re-throwing Error objects with added properties. This avoids the need for custom Errors.

```
Promise.resolve()
.then(function() {
    return readFile(false)
    .then(function (fileContents) {
        console.log('Successfully read the file:', fileContents);
        return fileContents;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        error.code = 521; // or whatever
        error.customMessage = 'Failed to read the file';
        throw error;
    })
})
.then(function (fileContents) {
    return validate(fileContents, false)
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log('Successfully validated the file:', result);
        return fileContents;
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        error.code = 522; // or whatever
        error.customMessage = 'Failed to validate the file';
        throw error;
    });
})
.catch(function(error) { // terminal catch.
    console.log(error); 
    // It's possible for unaugmented errors to reach this point,
    // so be sure to test for the extra properties before trying to use them.
    if(error.code) {...}
    if(error.customMessage) {...}
    // Note also that the original error.message is still intact.
});
```

The initial `Promise.resolve()` isn't strictly necessary, but helps keep everything else symetrical.

This will work with any Promises/A+ lib. Bluebird-sugar is not required.

Answer (score 3):

You can create custom Error types like so:

```
ReadFileError = function() {};
ReadFileError.prototype = Error.prototype;

ValidationError = function() {};
ValidationError.prototype = Error.prototype;
```

Then, you can `throw` from a Promise instead of rejecting:

```
function validate(fileContents, flag) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log('Validating file: ', fileContents);
        if (flag) {
            resolve('Validate passed');
        } else {
            throw new ReadFileError('readFile error');
        }
    });
}
```

Then you can catch different errors based on their types:

```
readFile(false)
    .then(function (fileContents) {
        console.log('Successfully read the file:', fileContents);
        return fileContents;
    })
    .then(function (fileContents) {
        return validate(fileContents, false);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log('Successfully validated the file:', result);
    })
    .catch(ReadFileError, function (err) {
        console.log(..., err);
    })
    .catch(ValidationError, function (err) {
        console.log(..., err);
    })
    catch(function(err) {
        ...
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I knew about this solution and as I mentioned throwing different exception is not in hand. I m using `bluebird.promisifyAll` method to wrap fs`, `mysql` methods with Promise. Those methods will simply resolve or reject based on the callback invocation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe more people could get the same problem. I personally don't think this is the best way to do this, because then you have your app throwing pseudo error, which could mistakenly be processed by other error processing on your server. But it works like you proposed:

```js
    // pseudo function to read file contents - resolves when 'flag' is true, rejects when 'flag' is false.
function readFile(flag) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log('Reading file...');
        if (flag) {
            resolve('File contents');
        } else {
            throw new Error ('errorReading');
        }
    });
}

// pseudo function to validate file contents - resolves when 'flag' is true, rejects when 'flag' is false.
function validate(fileContents, flag) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.log('Validating file: ', fileContents);
        if (flag) {
            resolve('Validate passed');
        } else {
            throw new Error ('validationFailed');

        }
    });
}

readFile(false)
    .then(function (fileContents) {
        console.log('Successfully read the file:', fileContents);
        return fileContents;
    })    
    .then(function (fileContents) {
        return validate(fileContents, false);
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        console.log('Successfully validated the file:', result);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.name);
        console.log(error.message);
        if (error.message === 'errorReading'){
            console.log('error 500 - File could\'d be read');
            // Maybe more custom error processing here
            //return res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
            //           'status' : 'error',
            //            'message' : 'File could\'d be read'
            //}));
        } else  if (error.message=== 'validationFailed'){
            console.log('error 500 - Validation not OK');
            // Maybe more custom error processing here            
            //return res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
            //            'status' : 'error',
            //            'message' : 'Validation not OK'
            //}));
        } else {
            console.log('error 500 - Some really bad stuff!');
            //return res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
            //            'status' : 'error',
            //            'message' : 'Some really bad stuff!',
            //            'errorMessage': error
            //}));
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.4.6/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```

*Please note that I commented out the `res.send` of express to avoid errors on the processing of this snippet!*

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand what you want to achieve i would suggest always using one single catch block (when can be avoided introducing nesting in promise logic which is totally ok in few use cases, but should be avoided when it can be, because you will potentially ends up with promise hell with indentation all around)

Can you handle all errors in your functions `readFile`, `validate` in uniform way like:

```
const error = new Error('something bad happened')
error.status = 500
return reject(error)
```

Then you could do you handle error logic within one single catch block based on `status` such as `res.status(err.status || 500).json(...)`