# How to stop executinf function after certain amount of time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
function avoidAfterTime() {
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
var interval = setInterval(function () {
    if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 3000) {
        clearInterval(interval);
        console.log("more than 2 sec")
        return;
    }
    longWorking();
}, 2000);
}

avoidAfterTime();

function longWorking(){
    var t;
    for (i = 0; i < 1e10; i++) t = i;
    console.log(t);
}
```

Hello. I am very new to JS. But I need to stop running some function (here it is longWorking) which can be executed for few seconds or for so much time. And I want to abort the function in case of it takes too long. I guess I know how to make it using, for example, threads in some other programming language. But I have no idea about making it in JS. I thought in this way (above)... But it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: It cannot. JS is a single thread language and nothing will execute till `for (i = 0; i < 1e10; i++)` ends. Only way is to check inside loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to terminate the script in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/550574/how-to-terminate-the-script-in-javascript)

Comment: It's so sad. I have almost understood that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm, I drafted this example. So it's a function that runs every second and if it takes more than 6 seconds it will stop. So basically you can put your work load in the **doSomething()** function and let it work every second and stop it if it takes too long. Or you can stop it based on a value. It depends on what do you want to do with it. I used the module pattern to isolate the logic and the variables. So you can encapsulate your logic in a module like way.

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    let timing = 0;

    const interval = setInterval(doSomething, 1000);

    function doSomething() {
        timing++;

        if (timing > 5) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }

        console.log('working');
    }
})();
```

Is this something you are looking for?

Comment: Hmm wired. I've pasted the code into a chrome console and it stops at the 6th **working** message.

Comment: Let me create a jsfiddle real quick