# How to stop execution after changing window.location?

Tags: javascript

Say I have some mobile check at the very top of my script:

```
if (isMobile) {
    window.location.href = '/m/' + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
}
```

And I also have some metrics down the code (or *even in some other module that is loaded asynchronously*) that are being sent to my metrics server.

My question is: how can I stop execution of everything that goes below my `window.location` change? Or even better, how to stop the whole javascript engine so that it doesn't execute any other asynchronously loaded modules?

I know that I can do mobile proxying in many different ways, but in this task my mobile redirect must be run on the client side, it is a given.

Comment: have you tried return false; after that.

Answer (score 7):

```
if (isMobile) {
    window.location.href = '/m/' + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's simple: `return false`...

```
if (isMobile) {
    window.location.href = '/m/' + window.location.pathname + window.location.search;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

There is `exit()` function implemented in javascript.

[How to terminate the script in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550574/how-to-terminate-the-script-in-javascript)

Comment: It's not implemented in JavaScript; it's a (discontinued) user-created script.